# Помогите разобраться с promise на примере перебора массива созданного с помощью $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, promise

Есть список элементов.
Я написал функцию которая перебирает их с задержкой, добавляя в массив `elements`, соответственно массив формируется не сразу. Как мне получить нужный элемент массива, уже после того как он будет собран?

читал в [этой статье](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6) как использовать **promise**, примеры написаны скорее всего для более опытных, либо они не подходят для решения моей задачи (не могу определить, так.

вроде бы, задача очень популярная, и в интернете должно быть полно примеров, один в один отражающих мое условие и имеющих решение, но что-то нет((

Специально собрал внизу пример, чтобы по нему кто-нибудь написал решение, так как это будет самый простой способ разобраться с **promise**

```js
var elements = [];
$('li').each(function(i, el) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    elements.push($(el).text());
  }, 700);
});
getResult(elements)

function getResult(elements) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    some.api.call(elements, function(data) {
      resolve(data);
      console.log(resolve(data));
    });

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>яблоко</li>
  <li>груша</li>
  <li>банан</li>
  <li>апельсин</li>
  <li>мандарин</li>
</ul>
```

попробовал на реальном примере уже с ajax:

```
$(files).each(function(i, file) {
  filesArr[i] = [];
  if (file.value) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(files[i].name, files[i].value);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/poc/" + controller,
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
    }).complete(function(data) {
      var result = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
      //var clearInput_name = result.input_name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, '');
      var clearInput_name = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve(result.input_name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, ''))
      });
      var clearInput_name_num = parseInt(result.input_name.match(/\d+/));

      filesArr[i].push(clearInput_name);
      /*                    filesArr[i].push(new Promise(function(resolve) {
                            resolve(result.file_name)
                        }));    
                        filesArr[i].push(new Promise(function(resolve) {
                            resolve(clearInput_name_num)
                        })); */
    });
  }
});
getResult(filesArr);

function getResult(filesArr) {
  // elements теперь промисы и нам нужно дождаться их выполнения
  Promise.all(filesArr).then(function(results) {
    // results - массив наших numbers
    new Promise(function(resolve) {
      asyncFn(results, resolve)
    })
  })
}

function asyncFn(data, callback) {
  console.log(data[0][0]);
}
```

оказалось что случай с each был довольно простой..

с ajax все равно выдает undefined

Comment: У вас тут вообще каша, почему `numbers` отложено вызываются? Зачем? И вызываются они через интервал, который к промисам отношение мало имеет

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @ThisMan. Что вообще такое `numbers`? Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: исправил... each я использовал для того чтобы показать что массив формируется не сразу. Вопрос в том, как мне получить любой из элементов массива, если я знаю что он формируется не сразу.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов вы видимо так и не поняли суть промисов, вам нужно в данном случае поместить весь вызов `ajax` в промис, и вызывать `resolve` в `complete` методе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте по порядку:

```
var elements = [];
$('li').each(function(i, el) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    elements.push($(el).text());
  }, 700);
});
```

Массив заполняется асинхронно, и какого-то простого способа узнать, когда именно он заполнится нет, если только не завести еще один таймер и там проверять длину массива. Но это не наш стиль, поэтому первым делом обернем создание массива в промис

```
var elements = [];
$('li').each(function(i, el) {
  // не буду тут заморачиваться на исключения
  elements.push(new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() =>resolve($(el).text()), 700)
  ))
});
```

Теперь в `elements` у нас массив промисов, которые выполнятся через какое-то время

```
getResult(elements)

function getResult(elements) {
  // elements теперь промисы и нам нужно дождаться их выполнения
  Promise.all(elements)
    .then(results =>
      // results - массив наших numbers
      new Promise(resolve => some.api.call(results, resolve));
    )
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Готовый пример:

```js
const elements = [];
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].forEach(function(el) {
  // не буду тут заморачиваться на исключения
  elements.push(new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() { resolve(el) }, 700)
  }));
});

getResult(elements);

function getResult(elements) {
  // elements теперь промисы и нам нужно дождаться их выполнения
  Promise.all(elements)
    .then(function(results) {
      // results - массив наших numbers
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        asyncFn(results, resolve);
      });
    })
    .then(console.log);
}

function asyncFn(data, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() { callback(data) }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: возможно рабочий только выдает ошибки, добавление удаление скобок не помогло ну и применить тоже не получилось из за этого

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Да, я там сам запутался с этими скобками)  Поправил ответ

Comment: спасибо, попробую сначала это как то на мои элементы из примера перенести... с цифрами совсем запутался. у вас на вход массив из цифр на на выходе рендомные числа, но как получить отдельный элемент массива для меня пока что все так же непонятно.

Comment: рандомные числа, потому что я так массив заполняю в цикле начальном. Я же написал, что в `results - массив наших numbers`, вот с ним и делайте что хотите в `then`

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов поправил

Comment: оказалось что случай с each был довольно простой.. с ajax все равно выдает undefined. Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Незнаю как вас, а меня нативные промисы всегда пугали. Вариант ответа ЭтогоМужчины, только с отсрочками от jquery:

```js
let elements = [];
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].forEach(() => {
  // не буду тут заморачиваться на исключения
  let promise=new $.Deferred()
  elements.push(promise)
  setTimeout(() => promise.resolve(Math.random()), 700)
});

getResult(elements);

function getResult(elements) {
  // elements теперь промисы и нам нужно дождаться их выполнения
  $.when(...elements).then((...results)=>{
    // results - массив наших numbers
    let promise=new $.Deferred()
    asyncFn(results, promise)
    return promise
  }).then(console.log);
}

function asyncFn(data, promise) {
    setTimeout(() => promise.resolve(data), 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```